# Change suffix of multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I have multiple text files with names containing 6 groups of period-separated digits matching the pattern `year.month.day.hour.minute.second`.

I want to add a `.txt` suffix to these files to make them easier to open as text files.

I tried the following code and I I tried with `os.rename` without success:

**Question**

How can I add `.txt` to the end of these file names?

```
path = os.chdir('realpath')

for f in os.listdir():

file_name = os.path.splitext(f)
name = file_name +tuple(['.txt'])
print(name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many problems in your script. You should read each method's documentation before using it. Here are some of your mistakes:

- `os.chdir('realpath')` - Do you really want to go to the `reapath` directory?
- `os.listdir():` − Missing argument, you need to feed a path to `listdir`.
- `print(name)` - This will print the new filename, not actually rename the file.

Here is a script that uses a regex to find files whose names are made of 6 groups of digits (corresponding to your pattern `year.month.day.hour.minute.second`) in the current directory, then adds the `.txt` suffix to those files with `os.rename`:

```
import os
import re
regex = re.compile("[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+")
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if regex.match(filename):
        os.rename(filename, filename + ".txt")
```

Comment: I will take care of your advises as well, thank you. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2017.12.22.12.19.29. -> '2017.12.22.12.19.29.txt' even there are files in the directory it says it couldnt find something @RonanBoiteau